# Importing into the SPS-Birthday field in Sharepoint from Custom Field in Active Directory, why does it always store a null value?

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, import, user-profile

For reference this is the User Profile Properties section of Sharepoint where you can start an import.  Ours is configured to interface with Active Directory.  We have mapped the SPS-Birthday field to a custom field in Active Directory since Active Directory doesn't natively store birthdays.

Everytime we try to import a birthday from Active Directory into the SPS-Birthday field in Sharepoint it seems to get absolutely nothing.  The SPS-Birthday field remains null.  We have tried changing the format of the date in Active Directory, and we are still getting a null value.

We even created a new Profile Property, but gave it a string datatype, and it was able to import the data from our custom Active Directory field.  I think the issue might have something to do with the DateTime format that is expected in sharepoint for the SPS-Birthday field.

Comment: We have already tried putting the date in these formats and they haven't worked, including your suggestion.  So just about most imaginable.

October 12
12/10
12-Oct
12 October
2000-10-12 00:00:00.000
2000-10-12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new attribute field in AD from the type of string(Generalized Time) and link this to your SPS-Birthday field in SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

The SPS-Birthday field takes values in the format "October 12", meaning it does not contains the year in the date. The format changes based on LCID, but never bringing years. Hope this helps solving the issue.

Comment: We have already tried putting the date in these formats and they haven't worked, including your suggestion. So just about most imaginable. October 12 12/10 12-Oct 12 October 2000-10-12 00:00:00.000 2000-10-12